# A bijection between a list of $n$ elements and the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: functions, linear-algebra

I have some lists omega[i], i=0,1,...,15.

And, e.g., omega[0] has four elements. I would like to define a function that maps omega[0][[i]] into $e_i$, where $e_1=\{1,0,0,0\}$, $e_2=\{0,1,0,0\}$... (The canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$)

However, I want to do this for all omega[i], that is, a bijection between omega[i] and the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^{\rm{Length[omega[i]]}}$

Comment: `omega[0] = {2, 3, 4, 
  5}; (f[omega[0][[#]]] = IdentityMatrix[Length@omega@0][[#]]) & /@ 
 Range@Length@omega[0]`

Comment: I think you're missing a multiplication with omega[0] somewhere in there to actually produce the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the lists in `omega` do not contain duplicate numbers, you can use something like this:

```
f[i_][j_] := 
  Flatten@
    IdentityMatrix[
      Length@
        omega[j]
    ][[#]]&@
      Flatten@
        Position[omega[j], i]
```

PS: You should clarify your actual intention in your question, I'm going on information from your comment to Sjoerd C. de Vries's answer here. And initially I interpreted the question like he did…